# When is a singleton service instantiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Given the following service registration:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(svc => new MyConcreteTpye(svc.GetService<MyEntityFrameworkContext>(), Configuration["Data"]));
```

I'd expect the `MyConcreteType` instance to be created automatically, but this is not the case. The constructor is never called.

Why am I required to do something like this so that the instance gets created?

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>();
```

The service is a listener so it's not explicitly called anywhere. Is this the wrong usage for a service?

Comment: `Why am I required to do something like this so that the instance gets created?` Because that is how dependency injection generally works. The thing isn't created until you ask for it. You aren't saying 'make me this thing now please'. You are saying 'if someone asks for `IMyInterface` later, here is how you should create it so you can give it to them'.

Comment: Consider using `AddSingleton(IServiceCollection, Type, Object)` instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions . That way you explicitly create the object and pass it in.

Comment: @mjwills if you see the constructor, I'm using the `IServiceProvider.GetService` method so that overload wouldn't work

Comment: In that case you'll need to keep doing what you are doing now, and just call `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>();` after all of your registrations are setup.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Where and when do you need it instantiated?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto by design the container will use the instance factory (which is the expression where you created your instance) when the desired type is first called/used. SO the earlier you call it the sooner it is instantiated for your use.

Comment: @Nkosi It's a message queue listener, so I'd need it ready as soon as possible. The problem with the approach of `GetRequiredService` is that Entity Framework has not finished configuring yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think services registered to `services` are supposed to be called explicitly somewhere, it might not be a good choice in your case.

If your "service" is running independent, perhaps you may do it like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IMyInterface _myService;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _myService = new MyConcreteTpye(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MyEntityFrameworkContext>(), Configuration["Data"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The problem is that `MyConreteType` gets called before the `MyEntityFrameworkContext.OnConfiguring` has finished, throwing exception